# How to solve the pile riddle in Ace Ventura Game?

Tags: ace-ventura

In the old Ace Ventura Action Adventure from 1995 you have to build a pile of 6 pieces in the right order, out of 8 pieces.

There are 20.160 different combinations. It turns out that this is the right one:

[image]

I found the solution using Google, but without explanation. How are you supposed to find the right combination? Building a combination together with a short animation takes at least 10s, so it's just impossible to simply try out all combinations.

Comment: What's the requirement of this build? This kinda looks like a.. woman?

Comment: There not really any requirement. The task is to build the correct 6 pieces together. You can find the task at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oW-nOgfYuJo 35:28

Comment: She just says "the most magnificent totem pole". Considering that the game has sexual allusions it's reasonable to build a woman-like body, the 2 odd pieces are just upper faces, so the actual number of possible combination is way lower.

Comment: @pinckerman oh.. the whole thing looks like a woman. Now I get it..

Comment: You are Adam, and you struggle building yourself a woman. This is quite funny.